# Change the cell width of a data frame in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame with one column which contains long text descriptions.

I would like to display all the text without truncating it, but in a manner in which the column makes wider instead of making the row higher.

If I let pandas' default settings, I get next:

[image]

But if I try to remove truncate using `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)`, the row gets higher while row width mantains almost equal:

[image]

Comment: When I try it in my notebook, the column actually gets wider with the command `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)` but also the row gets higher because I choose a very long text

Comment: setting `-1` returns `ValueError: Value must be a nonnegative integer or None` in pandas 1.0.0 why? is -1 deprecated. I want to have the behaviour of  `-1` screenshot above. how?

Comment: @ihightower: yes, I believe `-1` is deprecated as of pandas 1.0.0. But `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', None)` should give the same result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the below setting to change only for 1 column.

```
df.style.set_properties(subset=['ad_description'], **{'width-min': '300px'})
```

Edits: @Haritz Laboa: Thanks for confirming that 'width-min' works and not 'width'.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: I figured out that it works only if I use `width-min` instead of `width`. Change your answer and I'ill mark it as answered. Thanks ;)

Comment: I get:
 `KeyError: 'Styler.apply' and '.applymap' are not compatible with non-unique index or columns.'`

Comment: I am getting this error 
`Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:32: unexpected '['
1: df.style.set_properties(subset=[`
                                   ^